# Jquery calling function to parent element

Tags: jquery

I have got this html

```
<div class='Aname'>
    <div class='cllt'>
      <img src='../img/close.png' class='cl' />
      <div class='drag'>
        <img src='../img/dr.png' class='dr' /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this jquery function

```
function handle_mousedown(e){
    window.my_dragging = {};
    my_dragging.pageX0 = e.pageX;
    my_dragging.pageY0 = e.pageY;
    my_dragging.elem = this;
    my_dragging.offset0 = $(this).offset();
    function handle_dragging(e){
        var left = my_dragging.offset0.left + (e.pageX - my_dragging.pageX0);
        var top = my_dragging.offset0.top + (e.pageY - my_dragging.pageY0);
        $(my_dragging.elem)
            .offset({top: top, left: left});
    }
    function handle_mouseup(e){
        $('body')
            .off('mousemove', handle_dragging)
            .off('mouseup', handle_mouseup);
    }
    $('body')
        .on('mouseup', handle_mouseup)
        .on('mousemove', handle_dragging);
}
```

source [How do I make an element draggable in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424191/how-do-i-make-an-element-draggable-in-jquery);
And i have tried this way

```
$('.dr').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().parent(handle_mousedown)
});
```

But it is not dragging it

Comment: What do you expect `.parent(handle_mousedown)` to do? The argument to `.parent()` is a selector, it returns the parent if it matches the selector. It makes no sense to pass a function.

Comment: I had no idea what else i can do @Barmar

Comment: The question is missing something important: what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: When i mousedon on ".dr" it's parent element ".Aname" shoudl be dragged

Comment: Change `my_dragging.elem = this` to `my_dragging.elem = this.parentElement`

Comment: Put that in the question, not a comment.

Comment: It worked thanks! @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your function a second argument that indicates the element that should be dragged instead of `this`.

```js
function handle_mousedown(e, elem) {
  var my_dragging = {};
  my_dragging.pageX0 = e.pageX;
  my_dragging.pageY0 = e.pageY;
  my_dragging.elem = elem;
  my_dragging.offset0 = elem.offset();

  function handle_dragging(e) {
    var left = my_dragging.offset0.left + (e.pageX - my_dragging.pageX0);
    var top = my_dragging.offset0.top + (e.pageY - my_dragging.pageY0);
    my_dragging.elem
      .offset({
        top: top,
        left: left
      });
  }

  function handle_mouseup(e) {
    $('body')
      .off('mousemove', handle_dragging)
      .off('mouseup', handle_mouseup);
  }
  $('body')
    .on('mouseup', handle_mouseup)
    .on('mousemove', handle_dragging);
}

$('.dr').mousedown(function(e) {
  handle_mousedown(e, $(this).parent().parent().parent());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='Aname'>
    <div class='cllt'>
      <img src='../img/close.png' class='cl' />
      <div class='drag'>
        <img src='../img/dr.png' class='dr' /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```