# Draggable elements via touch on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make an item draggable via the mouse and via touch on iOS devices, without installing any new libraries such as jquery-ui.

The answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16448981/8799440
worked really well for the mouse events.

Below is what is retrieved from that answer:

```js
function handle_mousedown(e){
    window.my_dragging = {};
    my_dragging.pageX0 = e.pageX;
    my_dragging.pageY0 = e.pageY;
    my_dragging.elem = this;
    my_dragging.offset0 = $(this).offset();
    function handle_dragging(e){
        var left = my_dragging.offset0.left + (e.pageX - my_dragging.pageX0);
        var top = my_dragging.offset0.top + (e.pageY - my_dragging.pageY0);
        $(my_dragging.elem)
        .offset({top: top, left: left});
    }
    function handle_mouseup(e){
        $('body')
        .off('mousemove', handle_dragging)
        .off('mouseup', handle_mouseup);
    }
    $('body')
    .on('mouseup', handle_mouseup)
    .on('mousemove', handle_dragging);
}

$('#id').mousedown(handle_mousedown);
```

I've tried reusing this code, with all the touch counterparts for the mouse events such as `touchstart` instead of `mousedown`

But that as expected doesn't seem to work, I suspect this is because the touch API is completely different from the mouse API

Is there a work around to make this work?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml

Comment: Thank you! that helped alot. But, I've noticed is that, if both mousedown, and touchstart/enter are applied to the same div, it only registers the mouse event and not the touch (even on touch). Any idea why?

Comment: You need to make sure you're on a mobile device, and decide which to use in your logic. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/1584308