# How to make a draggable element using JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to make an element draggable using JQuery
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424191/how-do-i-make-an-element-draggable-in-jquery) but it didn't work because the scripts are not working and it looks like there isn't a link. Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#drag" ).draggable();
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #drag {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            cursor: all-scroll;
            background-color: aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="drag"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the files `js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js` and `js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"`?

Comment: I do not have the files. I need the links to the files like https://webstie.com/filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you did not have the files `js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js` and `js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js` present in your file system. I have replaced the files with CDN.

Find CDN here:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui

It doesn't necessarily need to be written after page load. But it can increase initial load time in some cases!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-uto9mlQzrs59VwILcLiRYeLKPPbS/bT71da/OEBYEwcdNUk8jYIy+D176RYoop1Da+f9mvkYrmj5MCLZWEtQuA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#drag" ).draggable();
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #drag {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            cursor: all-scroll;
            background-color: aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="drag"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do I need to include the "integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"" inside the 2 scripts

Comment: I personally would not use the JavaScript in the `<head>` Or above the `DOM` for that matter. --  See my answer ..   [REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638670/javascript-at-bottom-top-of-web-page)

Comment: @Zak I usually write my jQuery on head so that I can isebit outside `$(document).ready()`. The file will be cached on first load, and that wouldn't make much of a difference I hope.

Answer (score 1):

The order in your code plays an important role in things .. You need to load your scripts AFTER the DOM loads ..  Also --  Religiously view your `DevTools` `F12` -- The console gives vital information about DOM elements not being found, loaded etc etc ..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>  

    <style>
        #drag {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            cursor: all-scroll;
            background-color: aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="drag"></div> 
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#drag" ).draggable();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```